# Is float consistent across CPUs?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, cpu-architecture

If I run the exact same sequence of floating point calculations (e.g. in a C program) on two different types of CPUs that both implement the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), is it safe to expect both CPUs to return the same float number?

I ask this because different CPUs contain different Floating Point Units with different intermediate sizes (e.g. [80bit FPU in certain x86 architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision)) and I need to make sure that a simulation run across multiple different CPU architectures is deterministic, i.e. yields the same result given the same starting point regardless of the architecture.

Comment: I don't have any real experience on this, but "IEEE floating point", "cross-platform" and "deterministic" seem awfully like "good", "cheap", "fast": pick any two.

Comment: Moving my partial answer to a comment since somebody closed the question: Assuming IEEE arithmetic, almost, but not quite. The main issues are:

Comment: 1. Excess precision. If `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` (from `float.h`) is not 0, floating point expressions might be evaluated in a type larger than their nominal type. These types are given by `float_t` and `double_t`. Casting or storing to an object will drop the excess precision (rounding to the actual destination type), but this will not always give the same result as performing the original computation in the desired precision, due to *double rounding*.

Comment: Since double rounding only affects round-to-nearest mode, if you could run your computations in a different rounding mode, this issue would not matter as long as you were careful to cast away all excess precision.

Comment: 2. Aside from basic arithmetic operations and certain functions, IEEE arithmetic does not place strict requirements on the results of other functions, especially transcendental ones. Typically implementations aim for 1ulp max error, but that doesn't give reproducible results. You could avoid this issue by not using the math library, only using arithmetic.

Comment: @R.. In addition to `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, set by the compilation environment, there is the `FP_CONTRACT` user-set pragma to allow or disallow particular expressions to be evaluated with higher (specifically, infinite) precision in the course of computations. Typically, this allows the compiler to generate a fused-multiply-add instruction where the source code contains a multiplication and an addition. This can be seen as a case of excess precision but the details are different—for instance changing the rounding mode does not fix the issue. 6.5:8, 7.12.2:2 in C99.

Comment: From the comments and the suggested duplicate's answer I conclude that due to optimizations both during compilation and in the FPU, it is unsafe to assume float determinism. I'll go for fixed precision then ;)

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not specify floating-point semantics sufficiently to guarantee reproducibility between different C implementations. (If a C implementation adopts Annex F, it will help, but it is still insufficient, especially if the various transcendental functions in the math library are used.)

Techniques for obtaining reproducible results include limiting portability to C implementations that provide guarantees beyond those of the C standard, including necessary math library routines with the code rather than using the native library, writing in assembly language, and limiting the language features used.